Wavey ribbon of lines animation
What is the process to model and animate a ribbon made of lines (see attached image). The ribbon of lines I want to animate doesn't have to form a circle or infinity of lines as the image attached shows, most importantly it needs to be made up of lines forming a ribbon (or flag) flowing in the wind.
Where I'm stuck...I imported the line art as seen in the attached image, thickened the curves to 'bevel round'. How do I evenly space out the 'curves' to add dimension? Right now the imported artwork is flat.


This seems to be three questions in one, but it’s so vague it’s hard to tell. This StackExchange is for usage questions on one specific problem, not imagining general workflows for an entire project.

You can create an object A that is made of several torus meshes:

Create an object B that is a simple cylinder:

Make object B invisible, give a Surface Deform modifier to object A with object B as Target, click on Bind, also give it a Subdivision Surface modifier. Give object B a Cloth physic and a Subdivision Surface modifier, cut the Gravity in the Scene panel. Create some force fields like Turbulence and Force in order to animate object B, object A will follow:

File: 

Thanks for the feedback. After following these steps nothing animates, so a couple questions regarding that. 1. Does the cylinder object need to be open without the top and bottom closed as seen in your screenshot? 2. Can you give me sample input numbers to use and if I need to deselect or select any of the fields in the Physics Turbulence and Force tabs? 3. The torus rings need to be one object correct?

I've edited my answer to share the blend file, maybe share yours so that I can see what is the problem?

Oh great, I didn't see the attached blender file. Let me play around with my file using your inputs and I'll get back and reply here. Thank you

I added a camera to your file and mine, I rendered an image. The render is very different looking than what the camera is showing in the viewport. I tested to see if it's the camera causing the problem by adding a box in view. It's no the camera as it showed it at the same location and view as the viewport shows. If you add a camera to your file, you'll see what I mean. Any clue what I can do to match my viewport view to a render output?

Yes I see that, that's weird

Checking back here, any idea what can be done? Also, do you happen to know how to smooth out the animation so it doesn’t animate at a short frame rate? Because I adjusted the frame rate and it’s not doing anything.
